# adding maxlength to html:textarea

Tags: java, jsp, struts, tld

I want to add maxlength attribute to html:textarea. Im using struts1.
Tried to add ,

```
<dynamic-attributes>true</dynamic-attributes>
```

But it wouldnt work. What should I do to add maxlength to html:textarea. Im using Struts1 and do not want Java script to handle this. Is their a workaround? 
I tried Javascript now and used onkeypress attribute which returns false if length>256. However when you copy paste something and it ignores the length and allows you to paste in definite length. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The support for the maxlength attribute of textarea is HTML 5, which depends on browser support.  It isn't supported by Internet Explorer 9 and below or by Opera.  [This chart](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/03-maxlength.html) from wufoo shows current browser support.